# Firebase: How to create or access map in typescript / cloud function

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a map inside my document. Lets just call it map. Structure looks like this

```
-document
   -map
      {id: number}
      {id2: number2}
```

Now the very first time the function executes only the document exists and i want to create the map with the first entry.

Before first execution

```
-document
```

After first execution

```
-document
   -map
      {id: number}
```

Now whenever this executes with id, i increase the number stored inside the map

But if the id is not present inside the map it gets inserted.

For example calling it with id2 will result in the structure shown at the beginning.

```
await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async t => {
   const documentDb= await admin.firestore().doc(`document/${documentId}`).get()
   const document= documentDb.data()!
   if (document.map === undefined || document.map[id] === undefined) {
      const tempMap = {}; 
      tempMap[id] = 1
      document.map = tempMap
   }else{
      document.map[id] = document.map[id]+1
   }
   t.update(documentDb.ref, document);
}
```

This does not work (Well it actually does not even compile. Typescript complains here  `tempMap[id] = 1` because of an implicit "any" type. How can i achieve this (well i guess really simple) task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const tempMap : { [key: string]: any } = {}` should do the trick to solve your problem of "any" type.

In addition, note that you should not do `` documentDb = await admin.firestore().doc(`document/${documentId}`).get() `` in order to get the doc, but use the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#get) method of the transaction:

```
const documentRef = admin.firestore().doc(`document/${documentId}`);
const snapshot = await t.get(documentRef);
const document= snapshot.data()!;
//...
```

---

**Update: How to update the map**

```
const id = ...;
const updatePath = 'map.' + id;    // or id.toString(10) 
const obj = {};
obj[updatePath] = document.map[id] + 1;
t.update(documentDb.ref, obj);
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue with the any type is gone. Regarding the other issue: I did the same mistake before, you just saved me trouble. I also fixed the second issue, this came from the original code, but I simplified it for SO. I will test this now. I just realized that the code cannot work as it overrides the map if there already is a map but only a new Id is added.